# Rails has_many to same table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 2 tables

```
ACCRELATIONS
"ID"
"ACCDETAILS"
"ACCRELATIONSBIKEID"
"ACCRELATIONSCARID"
"ACCRELATIONSPERSONID"

ACCPEOPLE
"ID"
"FIRSTNAME"
"LASTNAME"
"ACCRELATIONSID"
```

the relations should be something like

```
class ACCPEOPLE < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :ACCRELATIONS, :foreign_key => 'ACCRELATIONSBIKEID'
has_many :ACCRELATIONS, :foreign_key => 'ACCRELATIONSCARID'
has_many :ACCRELATIONS, :foreign_key => 'ACCRELATIONSPERSONID'
```

Does this rails logic work? So basically an 'ACCPEOPLE' record can be joined on any of the three relations.

EDIT====

Thank you! I used the logic from your answer to fix the relation going the other way too now. Done by  adding the 3 relations as belongs_to in the other table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your association names should be unique. How can you access these associations if you give them the same name?

```
class AccPeople < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :bike_accelerations, :foreign_key => 'ACCRELATIONSBIKEID', :class_name => "<your_classname>"
has_many :car_accelerations, :foreign_key => 'ACCRELATIONSCARID', :class_name => "<your_classname>"
has_many :person_accelerations, :foreign_key => 'ACCRELATIONSPERSONID', :class_name => "<your_classname>"
```

Rename your associations to above.

Please follow [rails naming conventions](http://itsignals.cascadia.com.au/?p=7)

Comment: I am using an existing database structure. I agree, it is not ideal but I need to make rails work with it.

Comment: You can still follow rails convention for association name